# Angularfire seed login authentification disabled

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I downloaded the Angularfire seed chat app and I try to create an account but when I do I get the message "AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED". What does this mean and how do I change it so I can create accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, delegated authentication is disabled in Firebase.

To enable it for your Firebase, visit `https://<your-firebase.firebaseio.com` and visit the `Login & Auth` tab, where you can enable the authentication types of your choice.